# C++ Beginner: Shortcuts on Switch

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I was trying to write this code for an exercise that presents and allows the user to choose a beverage by entering a number corresponding to their beverage of choice (1 - 5). It would then print out specifying which beverage they chose, and an error message if they inputted anything outside of 1-5.

Below is the function code:

```
#include <vector>

std::string Vending (){
int num;
std::vector<std::string> beverage ={"Coke", "Sprite", "Water", "Pepsi", "7-Up"};
std::cin >> num;
switch (num){
  case (1) :
  std::cout << "You have chosen " << beverage[num-1];
  break;
  case (2) :
  std::cout << "You have chosen " << beverage[num-1];
  break;
  case (3) :
  std::cout << "You have chosen " << beverage[num-1];
  break;
  case (4) :
  std::cout << "You have chosen " << beverage[num-1];
  break;
  case (5) :
  std::cout << "You have chosen " << beverage[num-1];
  break;

default :
 std::cout << "Error, choice was not valid, here is your money back.\n";
 break;
}
}
```

The program works fine, but I was just wondering if there was a way to make the `switch()` shorter by let's say putting a range within case e.g. `case(//range from 1-5)` instead of writing each case individually per case number.

Any tips would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Hint: Notice that in every case, your code is exactly the same.  If you do the exact same operation **in all cases**, don't you just need to do that operation?

Comment: GCC supports `case 1 ... 5` as a compiler extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `if` statement would be more appropriate here, as `switch` blocks are not designed to operate on a range.

If you *must* use a `switch`, and are keen to write portable C++ (so the gcc range `switch` is not an option), then you could write

```
switch (num){
case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5:
    std::cout << "You have chosen " << beverage[num-1];
    break;
default :
     std::cout << "Error, choice was not valid, here is your money back.\n";
}
```

But it would be *far* more natural to write

```
if (num >= 1 && num <= beverage.size()){
    std::cout << "You have chosen " << beverage.at(num - 1);
} else {
    std::cout << "Error, choice was not valid, here is your money back.\n";
}
```

which has the added bonus that I haven't hardcoded the number of beverages. Using `at` also helps you guard against undefined behaviour since a vector bounds check is always taken (even if the statement is currently guarded by the `if`).

Comment: @NathanOliver: Because IO is going to be the bottleneck, and I only like to use `[]` in performance-critical situations. A habit of mine, and a good one, if I may say so myself. If I had a dollar for every exception I'd encountered when replacing `[]` with `at` I'd be a very very rich cat indeed. I guess an alternative would be to use `at` and catch the exception if thrown (ditching the `if` block), but that seems brittle to me.

Comment: Oh wow! I forgot to mention that the second part of the exercise was to convert either an if/switch statement to the other. This was so helpful! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `switch` or any kind of selection at all, just some basic check that the input is in range and then you print it:

```
if (num > 0 && num <= beverage.size())
{
    std::cout << "You have chosen " << beverage[num-1];
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Error, choice was not valid, here is your money back.\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I forgot to mention that part of the exercise was to practice using both if/switch statements.

Comment: @Sebastian `switch` could work, as shown in another answer. But I sure hope your teacher will tell you that it's not very good for this exercise once all students have returned their answers: A ´switch` have a fixed number of cases, each case *must* be a compile-time constant. If you want to add or remove elements from the vector, the `case`list needs to be modified, while an `if` range check will not.

Comment: Oh I see! That's really important to remember. Thank you so much again! :)